# core plot: how to add four axis on left,right,top and bottom side

Tags: ios, core-plot

default there is only two axis on left and bottom, I want to add another tow axis on right and bottom to show the same tick and label.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with constraints when making your axis,

```
CPTXYAxis *x = [self _makeDefaultAxis];
x.coordinate = CPTCoordinateX;
x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
x.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
// ...

CPTXYAxis *y = [self _makeDefaultAxis];
y.coordinate = CPTCoordinateY;
y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
y.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
// ...

CPTXYAxis *y2 = [self _makeDefaultAxis];
y2.coordinate = CPTCoordinateY;
y2.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithUpperOffset:0.0];
y2.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
// ...

CPTXYAxis *x2 = [self _makeDefaultAxis];
x2.coordinate = CPTCoordinateX;
x2.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithUpperOffset:0.0];
x2.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
```

Which gives something like,

[image: Box axis]

So also show the labels you need to adjust the padding etc.